# No application found in archive

Tags: iphone, loader, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit an app to app store through application loader. However, I am getting a message that "no application found in archive", from the loader. I have mode sure that my application is ready for upload and bundle-id matches given in the app summary. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried uploading directly through XCode? If you're having problems with the application loader it's worth trying the alternative route. Once you've built and archived your project, go to the XCode Organiser, select your chosen app archive, and hit the 'submit' button. That way you can be guaranteed you'll have the right binary.

I stopped using the application loader a while ago once XCode got the ability to submit straight to the app store.

Comment: Nope, they haven't - in the XCode 4 organizer there's a 'Submit' button in the Archive viewer, after 'Validate' and 'Share'. Either that or I dreamt submitting an app to the store through XCode 4 last week! :)